# How to filter dates in powershell using where-object from output of win32_reliabilityRecords

Tags: powershell-3.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a powershell script to get the failed hotfix which are 1 or 2 days old.

So I am trying to select 2 day old failed patches using where-object but it is not properly throwing the correct output.

Below is the command that I have written with the help of google.

```
$mail_body = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -Filter "SourceName = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" | Select-Object user, productname, @{LABEL = “date”;EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}} | where { $_.message -match ‘failure’ } | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
```

Comment: "it is not properly throwing the correct output" Do you met an error ? what do you get ? what do you expect ?

Comment: Thanks @JPBlanc for the response. I get a proper output but I wanted to filter the date. The output of that command will return all the failed updates/hotfix applied on the server. What I need is to get failed patches which are only recent. Let say those that were applied 2 days ago till current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should retrieve events that occurred in the last 7 days :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ReliabilityRecords -Filter "SourceName = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" |
    Select-Object { LABEL = "date"; EXPRESSION = { $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated) } } |
    Where-Object { $_.date -ge ([datetime]::today).AddDays(-7) }
```